# appendChild is not getting read in js file

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

not sure what is wrong missing in my code but in my js file the line using appendChild gets an error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at HTMLElement."

ionic is being used and i am trying to make the buttons work by having the user input a name and amount. Once clicked it outputs the text field contents.

JS:

```
const reasonInput = document.querySelector ('#input-reason');
const amountInput = document.querySelector ('#input-amount');
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector ('#btn-cancel');
const confirmBtn = document.querySelector ('#btn-confirm');
const expensesList = document.querySelector ('#expeneses-list');

confirmBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const enteredReason = reasonInput.value;
    const enteredAmount = amountInput.value;

    if (
    enteredReason.trim().length <= 0 ||
    enteredAmount <= 0 ||
    enteredAmount.trim().length <= 0
    ) {
        return;
    }
    const newItem = document.createElement ('ion-item');
    newItem.textContent = enteredReason + ': $' + enteredAmount;

    expensesList.appendChild(newItem);
});
```

MAIN:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Budget Planner</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <ion-app>
             <ion-header>
                 <ion-toolbar color="primary">
                     <ion-title>Budget Planner</ion-title>
                 </ion-toolbar>
             </ion-header>

             <ion-content>

                <ion-grid>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col size-md="6" offset-md="3">
                            <ion-card>

                                <ion-card-header>
                                    <ion-card-title>New Expense</ion-card-title>
                                </ion-card-header>

                                <ion-card-content>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label position="floating">Expense Reason</ion-label>
                                        <ion-input type="text" id="input-reason"></ion-input>
                                    </ion-item> 

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label position="floating">Expense Amount</ion-label>
                                        <ion-input type="number" id="input-amount"></ion-input>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <div margin-vertical text-right>

                                        <ion-button fill="outline" color="danger" id="btn-cancel">
                                            <ion-icon slot="start" name="close"></ion-icon>
                                            Clear
                                        </ion-button> 

                                        <ion-button fill="outline" color="tertiary" id="btn-confirm">
                                            <ion-icon slot="start" name="add"></ion-icon>
                                            Add Expense
                                        </ion-button> 
                                    </div>

                                </ion-card-content>
                            </ion-card>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>

                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col>
                            <ion-list id="expenses-list"></ion-list>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-grid>
             </ion-content>
     </ion-app>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The variable `expensesList` is undefined. You hage a typo in the selector: `('#expeneses-list')`

Comment: well thats a bit embarrasing, my bad and thanks. just wanted to have this fixed quickly.

Comment: That happens, glad it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

the id in html is expenses-list but you put expeneses-list id in app.js file so change the id it will work

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, provide some code along with your answer and make it more explanative. It is the best way for everybody to take benefit for your contributions! Have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)